# At what points does Ubuntu add entries to the UEFI boot list? How to prevent it?

Tags: boot, 18.04, uefi, 20.04

Ubuntu adds `ubuntu` to the UEFI boot list (it can be queried with `efibootmgr`). Does this only happen during initial setup of Ubuntu or does this also happen during some other time?

If so, how can I disable it, so that Ubuntu doesn't bother managing this entry (that is creating/updating it)?

I am asking this question for Ubuntu 18.04 *and* 20.04.

Comment: u mean the option in UEFI BIOS Boot Menu not in grub??

Comment: @PRATAP correct. Perhaps tagging it `grub2` was sort of ambiguous there. I went by the assumption that the two have something to do with each other. Let me remove that tag and replace it by something more sensible. What I am talking about is the aspect that can be queried and set via `efibootmgr`.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, that entry is only added during system installation. After that Ubuntu essentially uses GRUB to manage individual entries for the various kernel versions installed. See, e.g., https://askubuntu.com/a/1185257/158442 where someone wrote a whole tool for renaming entries, but doesn't mention having to rename again and again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of at least 3 where you can add boot options to EFI.

- During installation. This one is unavoidable.
- When doing `apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi`.
- When using [efibootmgr](https://linux.die.net/man/8/efibootmgr).

The last 2 are up to the user of the system so not executed by Ubuntu.

---

- `grub-install` does it too if you omit `--no-nvram`.

  ```
  --no-nvram
  Don't update the `boot-device'/`Boot*' NVRAM variables. 
  This option is only available on EFI and IEEE1275 targets.
  ```

> NVRAM is non-volatile RAM that is used in EFI to store variables that need to persist between boots. Many of these NVRAM variables are architecturally defined, and setting invalid options to NVRAM could cause a machine to not be able to boot.

Comment: Excellent. That information helps. Should I uncover another "source" for this entry, I'll attempt to track it down and update your answer or write my own. Thanks.

Comment: Oh and you could always add in a "efibootmgr delete" for "ubuntu" during startup if you want to get rid of it

Comment: The `grub-install`-command is worth mentioning, at least it has a `--no-nvram`-option.

Comment: @mook765 thanks :) added  bit about the option and nvram itself