# Can I create two "independent workspaces" with the same hardware/laptop on different SSDs?

Tags: dual-boot, ssd, workspaces

I have one laptop with two SSD slots. I'm considering buying an SSD for the second slot to create "two independent workspaces" with the same hardware/laptop.

The OS (both Ubuntu), applications, storage, should be completely independent, i.e., I don't want the admin/users on SSD1 to see the the admin/users on SSD2. If one application is only installed in SSD1, I don't want the users on SDD2 to have access to it.

When I boot I have the option "Boot device list F12 option". Under that option I can see the current SSD drive. If I install a second SSD I imagine that I will see the second SSD as a bootable option.

Would that be a way to achieve my goal of "two independent machines" within the same laptop?

Would this be safe, ie, if one of the SSD drives is attacked, would the other SSD be invisible to any attackers?

Thanks!

---

I posted something similar, but I don't think I was quite specific, hence this new post. I thank all the people that answered the other one.
[Dual Boot from Two different disks BOTH with ONLY Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360931/dual-boot-from-two-different-disks-both-with-only-linux)

Comment: Sure it is, both OS need to be installed with Full disk encryption. But the usual way would be to chose the OS from the bootloader (Grub), not the Bios. Imo, the answer to your original question is very valid.

Comment: I think instead of asking a new question, you should edit and specify your [original one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360931/dual-boot-from-two-different-disks-both-with-only-linux).