# Tools for creating a custom Linux OS based on Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, customization, custom-distributions, tools

I want to create a new OS which is based on Ubuntu. I changed everything in Ubuntu like name, screenfetch logo, etc., but I failed when it comes to creating an iso for my OS. I want to change everything like bootloader logo, bootloader name, etc. I don't want to show any Ubuntu name in that. I also want to change the grub screen. Which tools/packages do I need to install for that?

In particular I want to know which tools are generally used by Lubuntu/Xubuntu teams when they make their OS from an Ubuntu build.

Comment: You should read this before creating another OS. https://itsfoss.com/desktop-linux-torvalds/

Comment: Lubuntu & [official Ubuntu flavors](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) don't create our own ISOs, they are built by Ubuntu infrastructure. I can provide links to the Lubuntu infrastructure, but it only deals with code, CI, testing etc. as the building of ISOs is performed on Ubuntu infrastructure. The same applies to all *flavors*.  Ubuntu wiki pages document how Ubuntu ISOs are built.

Comment: FYI:   I'd start by reading a blog from someone who did it, eg. I remember reading & appreciated the writings of the Jacquees ??? who does Makulu.  He blogged about what tool he used, then forked & released his version used by himself in creating Makulu Linux when it was switched from Debian base to Ubuntu base many years ago (I used to read his stuff on g+; it was a little before g+ disappeared but g+ links were just elsewhere)..

Comment: The tool *currently* used by Lubuntu is https://phab.lubuntu.me/ (*you'll have to be quick to see it; we're currently moving our infrastructure and its being replaced!*) though of course most of use text editors (`vim` seems to be preferred) and commands to build & upload packages - as builds as already stated are done for all *flavors* by Ubuntu infrastructure just as with Ubuntu ISOs.  We don't change any graphic/name, we have our own package which contains what we want which is seeded on the ISO (https://git.launchpad.net/~lubuntu-dev/ubuntu-seeds/+git/lubuntu)

Comment: My prior comment should also have included https://phab.lubuntu.me/w/release-team/iso-building/ as well as the global link I used

Answer (score 6):

Read **https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DerivativeDistroHowto**

> I changed everything in Ubuntu like name, screenfetch logo, etc., but I failed when it comes to creating an iso for my OS.

Modify the Pretty Name Variable in `/usr/lib/os-release` and change "Ubuntu" to the name you prefer. For changing the icon, run:

```
sudo cp -r /usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/ubuntu-logo-icon.png /usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/ubuntu-logo-icon.png.bak
```

And then place the logo's `.png` file in `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/` and rename the `.png` file to `ubuntu-logo-icon.png`.

> I want to change everything like bootloader logo .

I assume you are talking about the boot splash screen, right? See [How do I change the plymouth bootscreen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2007/how-do-i-change-the-plymouth-bootscreen)
You can get one Plymouth them from [Pling](https://www.pling.com/browse?cat=108&ord=latest) or create your own theme.

> , bootloader name, etc. I don't want to show any Ubuntu name in that

See [How to safely change OS name in grub boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/759600/1460940) You have to modify `/etc/default/grub`.

> Which tools/packages do I need to install for that?

A.F.A.I.K, there is no such tool/package.

> I also want to change the grub screen.

I presume you're talking about the Grub theme. You can select one theme from
[Pling](https://www.pling.com/browse?cat=109&ord=latest) or create your own theme.

> In particular I want to know which tools are generally used by Lubuntu/Xubuntu teams when they make their OS from an Ubuntu build.

They don't really use any tool, they modify the files and repositories themself.

Comment: Thank you so much , you really help of every aspect . I am now going to do really crazy.

Comment: Awesome! Have fun! You may accept my answer by clicking the checkmark near the vote count.

Comment: You can use ```cubic``` to manipulate iso-files. Add/remove kernel-features and programs. Or you can do things to your excisting OS, like I think your doing given the useful answer by Someone (+ for Someone) and make an iso with ```ISO Master```.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend Cubic but you have to still go around and change branding, make your own DE, etc.
I recommend building the desktop and server versions on Ubuntu Server with Cubic, it gets rid of those pesky DE bits scattered everywhere.